# Import a helper function within an integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

I have an **integration test** where I need to call the **log_in function** (defined in Session Helper) whose parameter is a **user created within a fixture**.

`app/helpers/sessions_helper`

```
module SessionsHelper
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

Then I have the following fixture `test/fixtures/user.yml`

```
johndoe:
  first_name: John
  last_name: Doe
  email: john@doe.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

And then the following integration test `test/integration/user_navigation_test`

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserNavigationTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:johndoe)
  end

  test "login with invalid information" do
    log_in @user
  end

end
```

When I run the test, I have the following error.

```
ERROR["test_login_with_invalid_information", UserNavigationTest, 1.2090159619983751]
 test_login_with_invalid_information#UserNavigationTest (1.21s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `log_in' for #<UserNavigationTest:0x000000065cb3f8>
            test/integration/user_navigation_test.rb:10:in `block in <class:UserNavigationTest>'
```

I've tried to declare the log_in function within the `test_helper` but it didn't work either ; something to do with the configuration apparently.

How can I handle this?